# Question on image formation using convolution

Tags: optics

I have noticed that when discussing the resolution of a microscope or imaging system, the diffraction limit is often cited as the determining factor for what is resolvable or not. However, I am still unclear on how this impacts detection. For instance, in a reflection microscope, why does the point spread function (PSF) of the illumination affect the detection resolution?

Additionally, the widely-accepted theory of image formation involves convolving the object (which is assumed to have infinite resolution) with the PSF of the optics. I find myself questioning the validity of this theory, as I have not been able to find a satisfactory explanation for it. I recently learned about Image Scanning Microscopy (PRL 104, 198101 (2010)), which suggests that the PSF can be interpreted as the detection probability distribution for each camera pixel. I guess this could explain how techniques like STED can achieve resolution beyond the diffraction limit, though I am not familiar with the mechanics of STED. I have two questions in this regard:

1. What is the rationale behind describing the PSF as a probability distribution, and why is this distribution dependent on parameters such as wavelength, refractive index, and NA?
2. Why is the operation of image formation a convolution, rather than a cross-correlation, which seems more intuitive?

Comment: If you have already seen all these to such mathematical depth, have you seen the Fourier expression of these things? Convolutions are mathematically more natural to appear than cross-correlations.

Comment: I am not familiar with Fourier optics. All I know is that Fourier transforming an aperture is the far field approximation to the integral of the Huygen wavelets. I don't understand why everybody seems to use this Huygen wavelet model. Doesn't this just work for spatially coherent source? Am I missing something?

Comment: Anyway, how can I understand this problem using Fourier transformation? That the PSF can be explained with Fourier transform? Won't that be my first point? As in this explain the illumination spot size but not the detection? 
Regarding the second question, why is convolution more 'natural'? It seems cross correlation is more natural. I don't understand why you have to flip the PSF/object.

Comment: what do you mean by this: "the widely-accepted theory of image formation involves convolving the object (which is assumed to have infinite resolution) with the PSF of the optics"?

Comment: Image formation is always explained using I(r)=PSF(r)*O(r) where PSF(r) is the point spread function, O(r) is the object emission and * is the convolution operator. I have never seen any other equations. Are there other models?